# Why is pyproj shifted by 33 feet from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyproj

I have written a script to take WGS84 coordinates and convert them into a projected system for importing into a CAD program. I thought I had everything working when I decided to use QGIS to confirm everything was working. But the results are about 33 feet off (mostly shifted in the x).

I'm converting everything to EPSG 26741

```
...
project_to = pyproj.Proj(init=epsg_code, preserve_units=True)
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
...
easting, northing = pyproj.transform(wgs84, project_to, lon, lat)
```

[image: Green is QGIS projection and yellow is Pyproj projection.]

Green is QGIS projection and yellow is Pyproj projection.

Comment: I suspect that either they're using different datum transformations or one isn't using any at all.

Answer (score 2):

@mkennedy is probably correct. EPSG:26741 is based on NAD27, while WGS84 is essentially identical to NAD83 in North America. The amount of error you are seeing is very consistent with the difference between NAD27 and NAD83/WGS84.  I don't know exactly how to do this in QGIS or pyproj, but look at the underlying [proj4 documentation](https://proj4.org/operations/transformations/hgridshift.html) for more help. (It's also possible to supply a 3 or 7 parameter transform via the +towgs84 param: but I don't know what the shift params would be and I know you can download lots of VERY accurate grids from USGS for converting between NAD27 and NAD83.)

Comment: QGIS uses the ntv2 grid shift files for NAD27. Probably pyproj does not find them.